# Move one column to another dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame `df1` that looks like this:

```
userId   movie1   movie2   movie3
0        4.1      0.0      1.0 
1        3.1      1.1      3.4
2        2.8      0.0      1.7 
3        0.0      5.0      0.0
4        0.0      0.0      0.0
5        2.3      0.0      2.0
```

and another DataFrame, `df2` that looks like this:

```
userId   movie4   movie5   movie6
0        4.1      0.0      1.0 
1        3.1      1.1      3.4
2        2.8      0.0      1.7 
3        0.0      5.0      0.0
4        0.0      0.0      0.0
5        2.3      0.0      2.0
```

How do I select one column from `df2` and add it to `df1`? For example, adding `movie6` to `df1` would result:

```
userId   movie1   movie2   movie3   movie6
0        4.1      0.0      1.0      1.0
1        3.1      1.1      3.4      3.4
2        2.8      0.0      1.7      1.7
3        0.0      5.0      0.0      0.0
4        0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
5        2.3      0.0      2.0      2.0
```

Comment: `df1['movie6'] = df2['movie6']`

Comment: Use pd.concat where axis=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  df1=pd.concat([df1,df2['movie6']],axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge on the shared column, `userId`:

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2[["userId","movie6"]], on="userId")
```